# What is the optimal strategy in the "Factor Game"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

**Edit (Nov 1, 2015):** Bounty awarded, but the full question (i.e., *what is the optimal strategy*) remains *open* at the time of this update.

---

Consider the **Factor Game** played as follows:

Given a list of positive integers $1, \ldots, n$, two players (*red* and *blue*) alternate turns.

On each turn, the player picks and circles (in their color) any un-circled number $k$ that has at least one proper divisor yet to be circled; their opponent responds by circling (in their own color) all remaining proper divisors of $k$.

Then they switch (colors adjusted accordingly) and the game continues until there are no legal moves remaining.

At that point, each player adds up their circled numbers and the greater sum wins.

> **Question:** What is the optimal strategy in the Factor Game?

My *guess* is that, for large enough $n$, picking the number that nets the most points on each individual turn is optimal. For example, if $n = 49$, then the first player would pick $47$ (to net $46$) and their opponent would respond with $49$ (to net $42$). But this strategy is admittedly short-sighted.

(Clearly the strategy fails for some small choices of $n$ (the example of $n = 4$ is provided in the comments; $n = 9$ is another failure) but I'm okay with assuming $n$ is sufficiently large.)

I am hoping for a description of an optimal strategy and a proof that it is optimal (for $n$ large enough), but would be interested in special cases, heuristic arguments for what would be an optimal strategy, and heuristic arguments for why this problem is difficult.

---

**Motivation:** This game is sometimes played in elementary schools (or, in my classes, with elementary school teachers) to explore concepts like prime, composite, divisor, proper divisor, etc. In such a case, the numbers are usually presented in an array - often a *square* array, and so my particular interest is when $n$ is a square.

You can play the [**Factor Game**](https://illuminations.nctm.org/Activity.aspx?id=4134) through the NCTM (National Council of Teachers of Mathematics) *Illuminations* site if you would like to experience it for yourself.

Here is a sample board when $n = 49$ (presented as a $7 \times 7$ array):

[image]

Comment: The fact that there's a grid doesn't matter, does it?  The game plays out exactly the same on, say, a, 10-by-6 grid and a 15-by-4 grid, which both have 60 squares.

Comment: @MichaelLugo Right, although the game is typically played on a *square* grid: so, in particular, a 60 square board would not arise. For, e.g., the 6-by-6 board, it would (as you mention) not affect the strategy if it were presented as 4-by-9 etc.

Comment: I honestly believe that the fact that $n$ is assumed a square is purely practical for the recreational game and is of no interest in the actual problem.

Comment: The "pick the number netting the most points" strategy is not optimal for the $2\times 2$ game. Using this strategy, red picks $3$, blue gets $1$, blue picks $4$, red gets $2$, tie game. Red can win by picking $2$ or $4$ to start.

Comment: @JulianRosen Yes, there will need to be an assumption on the size of $n$. For the $3 \times 3$ game, the first move suggested here is $7$; I believe this results in a tie. If, instead, the first player picks $9$, then I believe player one can win.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva You are right that the constraint of $n$ being square may obfuscate the underlying structure of the problem; I have re-formulated the problem to address this.

Comment: By "optimal strategy" do you mean a strategy that produces the largest possible margin of victory, or are you satisfied with (possibly simpler) strategies that only guarantee a win (or, to be precise, a non-loss, since ties appear to be possible)?

Comment: Here is a failure of the greedy strategy for player 1 for $n=25$, the $5\times 5$ board: Denote by the numbers picked by the players on their turns:

(1) 23, 25 (2) 15, 21 (3) 14, 22 (4) 20, 15 (5) 24 OR 12, 18.  
Player 2 wins 128 to 124. Player 2's strategy was also the greedy one. 
However, we note that player 1 can force a win against the greedy strategy on the $n=25$ board by playing slightly differently. Indeed,

(1) 23, 25 (2) 22, 15 (3) 21, 20 (4) 16, 12 OR 24 (5) 18 Score: 128 to 110

Comment: @BarryCipra I am satisfied with a strategy that guarantees a win.

Comment: @EricNaslund Yes, martin's response contained precisely this example in an earlier edit - and, since my classes typically play with square $n$, this is an important case for me to keep in mind!

Answer (score 11):

**Clean-up on previous edits**

The *greedy strategy* may be described, as stated in the OP, for large enough $n$, as locally optimal number-picking so as to net the most points on each individual turn.

This fails for $1\leq n\leq 500$ for the following $n:$

$$4, 9, 25, 28, 29, 42, 52, 53, 54, 58, 59, 60, 61, 66, 77, 86, 102, \
103, 104, 108, 109, 114, 115, 117, 122, 123, 161, 162, 176, 177, 182, \
183, 184, 185, 187, 189, 194, 195, 210, 211, 216, 217, 221, 228, 229, \
238, 239, 243, 245, 247, 248, 249, 273, 282, 283, 286, 287, 288, 289, \
292, 293, 298, 310, 311, 312, 313, 324, 325, 330, 331, 333, 338, 339, \
343, 344, 345, 350, 351, 354, 355, 363, 364, 365, 369, 374, 375, 376, \
382, 383, 384, 385, 387, 391, 392, 395, 396, 397, 405, 407, 408, 409, \
412, 413, 414, 415, 420, 421, 429, 432, 433, 436, 437, 442, 443, 444, \
445, 452, 453, 458, 466, 467, 477, 482, 487, 488$$

In these cases (where for the original *"greedy strategy"*, one would pick the highest prime in the range to open the game), pick the highest odd semiprime in the range. From the opening choice onward, play the *greedy strategy*. This strategy results in a win for player $1$ for all $n\leq 500.$

With this approach, it is possible to avoid the *"play low"* game as described below, along with its obvious pitfalls.

Using the *MMA* code in the link below, one can find all opening numbers that give a win for player one (and thereafter playing as per *local optimal strategy*). Taking $n=25$, for example, which fails to give a win using the *local optimal strategy*,

```
With[{nn = 25}, 
Select[Transpose@{Range[2,nn],c4R[s1,nn,#] &/@ Range[2, nn]}, #[[2]] > 0&]]

%[[All, 1]]
```

gives $5, 7, 11, 25$ (hence, choose $25$ as the opening play since it is the largest odd semiprime in the given range) as the winning opening numbers for player $1$.

Likewise, testing the numbers that fail on the prime openings:

```
With[{nn = #}, c4R[s1, nn, Max@Select[Range@nn, OddQ@# == True && 
PrimeOmega@# == 2 &]]] & /@ {9, 25, 28, 29, 42, 52, 53, 54, 58, 59, 60, 61, 
66, 77, 86, 102, 103, 104, 108, 109, 114, 115, 117, 122, 123, 161, 162, 176, 
177, 182, 183, 184, 185, 187, 189, 194, 195, 210, 211, 216, 217, 221, 228, 
229, 238, 239, 243, 245, 247, 248, 249, 273, 282, 283, 286, 287, 288, 289, 
292, 293, 298, 310, 311, 312, 313, 324, 325, 330, 331, 333, 338, 339, 
343, 344, 345, 350, 351, 354, 355, 363, 364, 365, 369, 374, 375, 376, 
382, 383, 384, 385, 387, 391, 392, 395, 396, 397, 405, 407, 408, 409, 
412, 413, 414, 415, 420, 421, 429, 432, 433, 436, 437, 442, 443, 444, 
445, 452, 453, 458, 466, 467, 477, 482, 487, 488}
```

results in all positive values.

**Original answer**

Modifying the first choice to $2$ (as opposed to the largest prime in the range) where the *"short-sighted"* solution fails appears to be the winning strategy.

However, this does *not* hold for $n=77$:

```
Select[With[{aa = Select[Transpose@{Range@200, aa}, #[[2]] < 0 &]
[[All, 1]]}, Transpose@{aa, (Sign@bb)[[#]] & /@ aa}], #[[2]] < 0 &][[All, 1]]
```

`strat[n]` for any $n\geq30$ should then force a win for player $1$ for **most** $n$. Note that player $2$ plays the *local optimal strategy,* but, though I would be surprised if an alternative strategy could force a win for player $2$, this possibility is yet to be explored.

**Note**

Of course, since the game will be reversed if player $1$ chooses $1$ to start, and in so doing, allows player $2$ to go first, if player $2$ plays by the same strategy, he will choose $2$, etc., making the game rather absurd. A rule that either player may not forfeit a turn should then be adhered to, if a sensible solution is to be arrived at.

**Added**

I believe that the *local strategy* results in the longest game for large enough $n$. Interestingly, the length of the game for the *local strategy* for each $n\sim n/e:$

[image]

```
dd = {0, 0, 0, 0}~Join~(Length@s4[s1, #, Max@Select[Range@#, PrimeQ]] & /@ 
Range[5, 200]); ListLinePlot[{dd, Range@200/E}]
```

---

Mathematica code available [*here*](https://github.com/martinq321/MSE_Q_1494480/blob/master/MMA%20functions).

Comment: @BenjaminDickman sure - will add in a bit :)

Comment: @BenjaminDickman ran a test on opening with $1$ as opposed to $2,$ and shows complete symmetry as expected. Do you still want me to update with previous methods for $n<30?$

Comment: No, I'll just go through the edited versions if I need it. The direction the problem has gone is somewhat surprising... I think a proof of the symmetry with $1$ permissible is not too tough to sketch out [possibly just a sentence or two]. I'll give it some thought at another moment [unless someone else does, first]...

Comment: @BenjaminDickman there was an error with allowing $1$ to be selected, in that the code allowed $1$ to be selected twice. I hve ammended the answer accordingly, but of course, if this was the case, choosing $1$ first simply reverses who goes first!

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I thought the odd semiprime strategy was an improvement on the play low one, since the play low one could well have become far more complicated tactically. I can't see any way this technique can be beaten (unless of course it fails for larger $ n, $ which I supect it might). The immediate downvote that came following that update left me thinking that I must have missed something, but perhaps you are right - not all downvotes are entirely explicable! Of course it is sensible to leave the question visable on the bounty list in case you get a better answer in the meantime :)